# When do you use th:remove="tag" versus th:block?

Tags: thymeleaf

The following two blocks would evaluate the same, so when would you use `th:remove="tag"` over `th:block`?

`<th:block th:text="${myBean.value}">[value]</th:block>`

versus

`<span th:remove="tag" th:text="${myBean.value}">[value]</span>`

Comment: One idea is that you can put a condition in th:remove like specified in the documentation. Like this :
`<a href="/something" th:remove="${condition}? tag : none">Link text not to be removed</a>`

Comment: `<th:block th:if="${condition}">...`

Comment: I feel like `th:block` is always shorter without having to follow the semantics of where a `<span>` tag is allowed.  Just trying to see whether there's a case I don't see.

Comment: The if condition on th:block will remove everything. The th:remove condition will only remove the span tag if the condition evaluates to true. So not exactly the same, can be useful if you want html to display correctly without thymeleaf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since they can be used interchangeably I think it is opinion based... but for readability, my opinion is:

`<th:block />` should be used for doing structural logic (`th:if`, `th:each`, etc..) and only when it's not possible on the parent tag.  For example, in the case you have to contain more than one element in a loop -- e.g, a loop that produces 2 table rows for each object:

```
<table>
  <th:block th:each="object: ${objects}">
    <tr>
      <td th:text="${object.data1}" />
      <td th:text="${object.data2}" />
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
      <td th:text="${object.data3}" />
      <td th:text="${object.data4}" />
    </tr>
  </th:block>
<table>
```

`th:remove` should only be used for example data that should only be rendered when viewing the file in a browser/prototyping w/o rendering the thymeleaf:

```
<table>
  <th:block th:each="object: ${objects}">
    <tr>
      <td th:text="${object.data1}" />
      <td th:text="${object.data2}" />
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
      <td th:text="${object.data3}" />
      <td th:text="${object.data4}" />
    </tr>
  </th:block>
  
  <tr th:remove="all">
    <td>Mild Cinnamon</td>
    <td>1.99</td>
  </tr>
      
  <tr th:remove="all">
    <td>Other</td>
    <td>Data</td>
  </tr>
<table>
```

In the specific case where you want to output  data/text without a tag, I prefer inline expressions.  They're enabled by default in thymeleaf 3.  So:

`[[${myBean.value}]]` instead of `<th:block th:text="${myBean.value}">[value]</th:block>`

Comment: Maybe you're right and I'm just exposing my own preferences. Just thought that there would be a best practice of some sort.